# How to add two plots to single graph

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I have a set of results that in a .txt format. I want to display them on the same graph as a trend line of the points but it is not working. How can I fix this?

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        xlabel=$2B^2d^2$,
        ylabel=$V_a$,
        xmin=0, xmax=0.000000025,
        ymin=0, ymax=5500,]
        \addplot [mark=*,mark size=1.5pt, only marks] table[meta=Va] {E:mtab1.txt};
        
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

which produces this graph[image]

when I try to add a trend line with equation 2.445E11x+815 it does not work

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        xlabel=$2B^2d^2$,
        ylabel=$V_a$,
        xmin=0, xmax=0.000000025,
        ymin=0, ymax=5500,]
        \addplot [mark=*,mark size=1.5pt, only marks] table[meta=Va] {E:mtab1.txt};
        \addplot [mark=none, red, thick]{244500000000x+815};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

this produces a graph which looks like this [image]

any help would be great. I just started to learn LateX a couple days ago so I'm very new at this.

edit: here is the contents of the .txt file

```
2B2d2   Va
5.184E-09   1400
5.716E-09   1710
6.856E-09   2000
7.465E-09   2300
8.761E-09   2610
1.016E-08   2900
1.090E-08   3300
1.327E-08   3700
1.588E-08   4010
1.774E-08   4400
1.971E-08   4700
2.286E-08   5010
2.396E-08   5150
```

Comment: Hi Finn.  Please paste in a working example, including the data (not as a separate file, which we can't (won't) download).  To be clear, the ENTIRE code that actually compiles.

Comment: Perhaps you have to write '244500000000*x+815' (add a '*' before 'x'.

Comment: Raffaele that works thank you

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the issue was a typo in the proposed code, solved in comments.

Answer (score 1):

With this code (the line for data table plot is commented)

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            xlabel=$2B^2d^2$,
            ylabel=$V_a$,
            xmin=0, xmax=0.000000025,
            ymin=0, ymax=5500,]
            %\addplot [mark=*,mark size=1.5pt, only marks] table[meta=Va] {E:mtab1.txt};
            \addplot [mark=none, red, thick]{244500000000*x+815};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

You have this output:

[image]

If You uncomment that line (You have the file of data), You have the two plots at the same time.